# How do you say "medicine" in Latin without borrowing a Greek word?

Tags: classical-latin, word-request

Is there a "purely Latin" way of saying "medicine"?
The Smith & Hall and Goelzer dictionaries both give "medicina" as the only translation.

Is there a paraphrase like "ars curandi aegrotorum" attested in classical Latin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Medicina* is not a Greek word. It comes from *medicare*, which in turn is derived from *medeor*, which ultimately goes back to the Proto-Indo-European **med-*, and is cognate with the Greek μέδομαι (De Vaan).

If you want a different root, I'd suggest *sanare* instead of *curare* only because there's less ambiguity. It's not really classical, but you do see it in post-classical [works](https://www.abebooks.com/book-search/title/ars-sanandi-cum-expectatione-ubi-firmitas-fides-veritas-proborum-peritorum-medicorum-ostenditur-declaratur-confirmatur/).

For *curare*, you could also do something like *Ars Curativa*. The latter word is medieval, though, not classical.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but according to Meissner's Phraséologie, sanare is used for diseases and curare for people, I don't know if this is correct

Comment: @Victor I'm not sure that's correct, at least not absolutely so. Just quickly looking at Lewis and Short, I already see exceptions, e.g. from Ovid: "corpora vix ferro sanantur."